# how to insert data into two tables at a time using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, windows

i need to insert data which is in windows forms has to insert to two tables. i am using data source for all controls in windows forms. can you please sugest me how to insert data from windows forms into two tables at same time.

my table is like this

```
**product table**

pid   salePrice  


**Product_tax table**

pid  taxid
```

When i click on submit button product id will auto generate and salePrice has to store from form at same time what ever i select tax that also has to store in product_tax table along with product id. please help me out from this point.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So in order for you to do so, this is a simple example so that you can understand (**there are better and more sophisticated ways to do this**).

```
private void AddProducts(double salePrice, int taxValue)
{
    using (var ctx = new Entity())
    {

        Product prodObject = new Product
        {
            PId = //NEW ID,
            SalePrice = salePrice
        };

        Product_tax pTax = new Product_tax 
        {
            pid = prodObject.PId,
            taxid = taxValue
        };

        ctx.product.AddObject(prodObject);
        ctx.Product_tax .AddObject(pTax);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This should do the trick with a tweak to your solution.

Comment: are you sure you can't just do `Product = prodObject,` in pTax?

Comment: @Vogel612 Just to simplify the understanding of the code due to the question that was regarding the ID. That way, you can see on the code where it comes from and how it connects. :)

Comment: hmm. keep in mind that `pTax` also has a Tax. this is only a relational table (not that one would actually need it)

Comment: @Vogel612, yep... let's just assume there is more to it then the example... ;) but you are correct!!

Comment: What are the better and more sophisticated ways? How to dig more?

Answer (score 0):

quite simple. Given the case you have a relationship defined between the tables you can do the following:

```
using ( Entity EF = new Entity()){
    EF.addToProductTax(new ProductTax(){
        Product = new Product(){
            pid = //your generated Product id,
            salePrice = price
        },
        Tax = (FROM t in EF.tax where t.taxid == taxid select t);
    });
}
```

for easier comprehension:

```
Product item = new Product();
item.salePrice = price;
// pid gets generated automatically !

Tax correspondingTax = (from t in EF.tax where t.taxid == taxid select t);

Product_Tax add = new Product_Tax;
add.Product = item;
add.Tax = correspondingTax;
EF.addToProductTax(add);
```

Remember, this only works if you have a relationship defined between the two tables. in every other case you will have to do this:

```
EF.addToTax(new Tax(){
    taxid = taxid,
    // and all the other fields
});
EF.addToProducts(new Product(){
    pid = pid,
    salePrice = saleprice
});
EF.addToProductTax(new ProductTax(){
    pid = pid,
    taxid = taxid
});
```

Comment: ProdouctTax table.. Productid is FK of Product table and TaxID  is FK of Tax table. in store Procedure We can use @@Identity. But i am not getting how to use it in entity model

Comment: you should be able to just do: `ProductTax.Tax.property;`. so if I understand correctly, Product_Tax is just a relationship table. this means you can go even further: `Product.ProductTax.Tax.property;`. but to do this you will need to load the Entity Context.