# Using Linq query How to Insert data into two different table

Tags: c#

Here i'm using EntityFramework for inserting data into two different tables. Please suggest me how can i do

**ClassFile**

```
namespace ImageWithallCtrls.Models
{
    public partial class TwoTabes
    {
        public partial  class Employee
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string EMail { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Department> Department { get; set; }
        }

        public  class Department
        {
            public int DID { get; set; }
            public string D_Name { get; set; }
            public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
            public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult InserTwise(TwoTabes model )
{
     Employee emp = db.Employees.Create();
     emp.Name = model.Employee.Name;         
}
```

Here i'm Getting Error `"model.Employee.Name"`

Comment: hey checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142456/how-to-insert-data-into-two-tables-at-a-time-using-entity-framework

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: "model.Employee.Name" why model not accepecting model.Employee..

Comment: "model.Employee.Name" is not an actual exception, try surrounding your code with a try catch and pint out the type of the exception, its message and stacktrace. Add this to your question and we will be able to help (if this doesn't enable you to fix the problem by your self)

Comment: could u plz come in teamviewr

Comment: I think error is not coming from `model.Employee.Name` please debug and give detail about exact error.

Comment: after writing model.   i'm not getting Employee Name  i actually using Ado.net Entity Frame work   " public partial class TwoTabes"  its my private class